# How to cross compile a C SDL program for Windows on Linux?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, sdl, cross-compiling

I have a perfectly working C program using SDL that I can compile with

```
gcc main.c -o program `sdl-config --libs` -lSDL
```

The program is simple, it comes up with a black window and waits for the user to close it. No problems or errors. I have MinGW installed and I'm trying to use `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` to cross-compile it; I would like to know how to cross-compile this for Windows on Linux and include the necessary libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You can invoke MinGW’s GCC like your Linux version, but you might need to replace`sdl-config` with some manual configuration like so:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Ipath/to/SDL/headers \
                       -Lpath/to/SDL/libs \
                       -o program main.o \
                       -lSDL -lSDLmain
```

You will need to download *SDL.lib* and *SDLmain.lib*. I believe they are part of the development zip. (**Edit**: as noted in the comments, you might not need to use the libs but can just use the DLLs.)

This might pop up a console window when running. Pass in the `-mwindows` flag to target the Windows subsystem instead.

Comment: Aren'y `.lib`s for msvc while mingw uses `.dll.a` (or `.a`)? Also I think mingw can now link with dll directly without import libraries, at least for C. But since `SDLmain` is static-only it doesn't matter that much. Order of libraries should be reversed too (not sure here, it is with SDL2, haven't used 1.2 for quite a while).

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure and I wasn't able to test it. I'll update the answer.